# Converting a Swift function to Objective C and use returned value in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to write these two `Swift` functions in `Objective-C` and then call the returned values in `Swift` how do i go about doing this?

Also where do i need to put them in my `AppDelegate`?

Sorry this might be really easy but I have no experience using `Objective-C`.

Thanks in advance!

Functions to convert:

```
class func getAppDelegate() -> AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
}

func getDocDir() -> String {
    return NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
}
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application 
 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{

}
@end
```

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVAppDelegate.h>

@interface AppDelegate : CDVAppDelegate {}


@end
```

Comment: Why do you need to cross over into ObjC like this?

Comment: It is an objective C project and i need those two values in a swift file I am building but was told cant have a swift and objective C appDelegate

Comment: @alimcc56 but why? "and then call the returned values in"

Answer (score 1):

Here is your AppDelegate class written with objective-c including your Swift method. But we need to know more detail to help.

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVAppDelegate.h>

@interface AppDelegate : CDVAppDelegate {}

+ (id)getAppDelegate;
- (NSString*)getDocDir;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application 
 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}

+ (id)getAppDelegate {
    return self;
}

- (NSString*)getDocDir {
    return NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
}
@end
```

Comment: The function `getAppDelegate()` is a class method which returns the current instance of `AppDelegate`. If you make it an instance method, you need to access the current instance...

Comment: A little more, `-` to `+` for `getAppDelegate`.

Comment: What do you mean @OOPer?. Self and [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] are same.

Comment: When you keep it as an instance method, you need to use it something like `[anAppDelegate getAppDelegate]`, how do you get `anAppDelegate` to call the method? It's called from outside of the `AppDelegate` class.

Comment: @OOPer I got what you meant, and updated my answer thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need bridging header and thats it. Import your AppDelegate in bridging header file. The bridging header file is an interface for sharing code from objective C to Swift. So when you add any swift file to objective C project it will prompt you for adding  this header file. e.g. ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h. If its not there check how to create it manually [here](https://mycodetips.com/ios/manually-adding-swift-bridging-header-1290.html).

Then import all needed objective C files in this header as:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "Appdelegate.h"
```

Then you can add your mentioned functions in your swift file itself.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Ali's post seems to be the right answer for what you asked:

> write these two Swift functions in Objective-C and then call the
>   returned values in Swift

But if you mean you want to call the two methods only from your Swift code, why don't you define it in an extension.

AppDelegate+.swift:

```
import UIKit

extension AppDelegate {
    class func getAppDelegate() -> AppDelegate {
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    }

    func getDocDir() -> String {
        return NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    }

}
```

Of course, you need `#import "AppDelegate.h"` in your "...-Bridging-Header.h" .

You can use them as were in your own `AppDelegate`.